# Adding script with math functions to ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I am very new to ModelBuilder + python.

I am trying to make a model. Don't know if it matters to upload it. If you want i can.

I want to calculate variance from a points-shapefile with elevation data and want to add this script to my model:

```
### x = (column: GRID_CODE, from a shapefile from model builder)

average = sum(x) / len(x)
variance = sum((average - value) ** 2 for value in x) / (len(x)-1)

### output to a new shapefile
```

How could i make this script working? Searched a lot here and at arcgis help but couldn't find something.

Can't understand how to "grab" data from shapefile, process them through script and then print the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand the question - one way would be to use a [SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) - the cursor can vary slightly depending on your version of arcgis, but basically use the search cursor to total the value and calculate the average and variance.
something similar to:

```
numberOfRows=0
total=0
data=[]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('yourshapefile.shp','GRID_CODE') as sCursor:
    for row in sCursor:
        total=row[0]+total
        data.append(row[0])
        numberOfRows+=1
ave=total/numberOfRows
```

you could then calculate the variance (using your equation)

```
var=sum([(ave-value)**2 for value in data])/(numberOfRows-1)
```

or typically [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) is also installed with arcgis, so you could import numpy as np
and use

```
var=np.var(data)
```

which you could simply print to standard output.